# how i can pass the parameters values to MySql Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, swing

i have created MySQL stored procedure for the update query.

```
delimiter //
create procedure studentrcs(sname varchar(20),smark1 int(3),smark2 int(3),stotal int(10),inout Regno int(6))
begin
UPDATE studentrecords set student_name=sname,mark1=smark1,mark2=smark2,total=stotal where Reg_no=Regno;
end;//
```

After that, through callable statement how i can pass value(at run time) as parameter

```
CallableStatement calstat=null;    
calstat=conn.prepareCall("{call studentrcs(?,?,?,?,?)}"); // **how i can pass the value here(at run time).**
             //System.out.println("Update");
                    calstat.setString(1,tname.getText());
                    calstat.setString(2, treg.getText());
                    calstat.setString(3, tmark1.getText());
                    calstat.setString(4, tmark2.getText());
                    calstat.setString(5, ttotal.getText());

                    calstat.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Why you are not giving correct answers the points?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `INOUT` parameter specified (`Regno`) in your stored procedure so you'll need to both specify a value for it's input and register it with the `CallableStatement.registerOutParameter` method. Also, try setting `int` values for your `int` input parameters too.

For example:

```
CallableStatement calstat=null;    
calstat=conn.prepareCall("{call studentrcs(?,?,?,?,?)}"); // **how i can pass the value here(at run time).**
//System.out.println("Update");
  calstat.setString(1,tname.getText());
  calstat.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(treg.getText()));
  calstat.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(tmark1.getText()));
  calstat.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(tmark2.getText()));
  calstat.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(ttotal.getText()));

  calstat.registerOutParameter(5, Types.NUMERIC);

  calstat.executeUpdate();
```

I'm assuming that all of this is in a `try catch finally` block so I have left out handling the `NumberFormatException` that will be raised if `tmark1.getText()`, `tname.getText()`, `tmark2.getText()` or `ttotal.getText()` return not valid integer values.

More info about calling MySQL routines from Java [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/storedprocedures.html)

As an aside I don't know why you just don't just dump the SQL update method into it's own Java method and call that rather than creating a stored MySQL routine. Just my opinion though!